# Change text color/colour in 16 bit real mode assembly using int 0x10 and ax = 0x07

Tags: assembly, operating-system, bios, 16-bit, real-mode

I noticed when using the 0x07 (scroll/clear screen) function in 0x07 that there is an attribute for screen colour (in bh). I noticed that `help color` listed all these colours so I changed what was originally 0x07 (white on black) to 0x0a (green on black) but it did not function as I expected and the screen stayed white on black. I have a feeling that I need to change the display mode but I'm unsure on how to do that.

```
clearScreen:
    pusha

    mov ax, 0x07    ; function to scroll window
    mov bh, 0x0a    ; Does not work
    mov cx, 0x0000  ; row = 0, column = 0
    mov dx, 0x184f  ; row = 24 (0x18), column = 79 (0x4f)
    int 0x10        ; call the BIOS interrupt

    popa
    ret
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mov ax, 0x07` should be `mov ax, 0x0700` because the function number belongs in `AH`, and the number of lines in `AL`. Also note that the screen will stay black of course, since a space with green on black is still black. The cursor will change to green, though. You could try black on green for some effect, ie. `mov bh, 0xa0`.